# How to modify uitable cell height (row height) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I have a uitable with 6 row and 6 column and i want to show it in full screen mode for doing this i can change column width but i can't change row height.
Extent is Size of uitable rectangle,  but it is read only properties.

Comment: do you want to increase the font size as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conventional approaches the only possibility to change the row height is by adjusting the `'FontSize'` property.

The following function will give you a full-screen table. You can set up `'ColumnWidth'` and `'FontSize'` until it fills your screen entirely.

```
function fancyTable 

columnwidth = { 1920/2 1920/2 };
FontSize = 135;

h = figure('units','normalized','Position',[0 0 1 1],...
           'numbertitle','off','MenuBar','none');
defaultData = rand(5,2);
uitable(h,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 0 1 1],...
              'Data', defaultData,... 
              'ColumnName', [],'RowName',[],...
              'ColumnWidth', columnwidth,...
              'FontSize', FontSize,...
              'ColumnEditable', [false false],...
              'ColumnFormat', {'numeric' , 'numeric'});
end
```

[image]

---

I don't see a simple solution to change the row-height independently from the font size.

But there are some ideas at [undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uitable-customization-report/).

"
**7. JIDE customizations**
... *Similarly, this section explains how we can use JIDE to merge together adjacent cells:*
"

[image]

Could be a fiddly workaround, and there are no code-examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. use the `findjobj` utility from the file exchange.
It will get you to the underlying java object of the table, somewhere along the lines of:

```
t = uitable(...);
scrollPane = findjobj(t);
% not 100% sure about this, but there'll be a `UITablePeer` object somewhere within that scrollPane
jTable = scrollPane.getComponent(0);
```

This `jTable` will have a `setRowHeight` method inherited from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html